# Summing Columns up with some exceptions

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am working on a database with two different tables.
The first contains every change in the database like a transaction table. It contains the object that was bought/sold, how many of them where bought/sold, when this tranaction happend and in which place.
The second table contains the total value of every object that should be available in those places.

Now here is my question:
I want to automaticly sum up every entry with the same object and location inside of table one and save this value inside of table two.
BUT
Sometimes there are special entrys in table one which should not be summed up with the other values. They should overwrite the value.

I have an example of how this summing up should look like:

```
n = normal value, s = special value   
n:  1  sum:  1  
n:  2  sum:  3  
s:  7  sum:  7  
n:  5  sum: 12  
n:  4  sum: 16  
n:  7  sum: 23  
s: 20  sum: 20
```

To help you help me I have some additional informations:
There are 4 columns inside of table one

The first one is called object and contains the object number for which this entry takes effect.

The second column contains the amount of that object. Whether it was bought or sold.

The third column tells me on which locations this transaction belongs to. Which also means that every object has different amounts depending on the location.

The fourth column contains an information why this transaction happend. It tells me if this transaction happend because I bought something or because I sold something OR because I counted my stock.
This is the special indicator which should tell my database not to sum up this value but instead overwrite the previous one with this.

The fifth and last column contains the date when this transaction happend. This is very important because the whole table is sorted by the date. And it tells when those special values come in place.

The other table just contains the summed up value for every object in every location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This below will return the sum of each record for a particular Object 'MyObj' starting from the last instance of a 'Special' entry (inclusive).

*(Untested)*

```
SELECT Sum(a.Amount) AS TheSum
FROM tblMyTable a
WHERE ID_PK> = nz((
    SELECT max(ID_PK) 
    FROM tblMyTable 
    WHERE Object=a.Object AND IsSpecial=1
),0) 
AND a.Object='MyObj'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try it as soon as i am back at work and give you feedback after i tested it.

Comment: Okay, your answer seems to work but there is still one thing missing. I need this code to be executed every time a new entry is added in table 1. And then the sum needs to be inserted in table 2.

Comment: @AlfredEmsenhuber
You shouldn't need to insert it into a table, you should just be able to use the query in place of the table (or LEFT/RIGHT JOIN it in to existing query).

In the majority of cases it is bad practice to insert sums into tables, from other tables. However, if you are strongly set on doing it, look at [data macros](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200?CorrelationId=8142a824-e190-4c88-b98b-f7bd30546594&ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA)

Comment: Okay i see. Well then thank you very much for your help. I'll change the database to use your code as query instead of saving it into a table.